# Not able to run app on MobileFirst 7.1 Android simulator

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Import the sample Hello World app (v7.0 version) to MobileFirst 7.1 (7.1.0.00-20150913-2345), deploy and run on Android simulator, getting an alert dialog with an entry gap_init:2 and two buttons, if dismiss the dialog with OK or Cancel button, the hello world page does shown. However, if run our app which has adapter call to server, the app doesn't run after dismiss the dialog. The same app can run in iPhone simulator without any problem.
Browser console log has this error after the alert dialog pops up : 
**TypeError: this.vectorLayer is undefined** 
after dismiss the dialog, console log add this error:
**TypeError: cordova.exec is not a function**
I found other people have reported similar error for v7.0. and wonder whether it is fixed or not.

Comment: You took a 7.0 sample and imported into 7.1 what happens when you use a 7.1 sample in 7.1, or even better - create your own project and app and test there?

Comment: I cannot find 7.1 Hello World to download. I'll create my own to try.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is in fact not related to the Android Emulator, but to previewing the Android environment in the MobileFirst Console's MBS. This happens due to a regression and is taken care of in *APAR PI50036 CORDOVA "GAP_INIT:2" ERROR WHEN PREVIEWING ANDROID IN MBS*.

---

I cannot confirm this.
I am using the latest 7.1 iFix available from IBM Fix Central (I am using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio   7.1.0.00-20150929-1541)

1. Created a new project and application, added the Android environment
2. Added WL.Client.connect() code that displays alert in case of successor failure, in common\js\main.js
3. Launched in Android Emulator (AVD running 5.0.1)

My alert showing "success" was displayed.

The only thing I had to make sure of is that the app is connecting to the correct host in the generated Android project > assets > wlclient.properties, changed the host value from "mbp-idan" (my hostname) to my actual IP address.

Comment: I am having problem with Android Simulator. Now I noticed in wlclient.properties file the wlServerHost property uses hostname even the wl server config uses IP address. The wlclient.properties file is regenerated when redeploy to server, and change will be overwritten. How you manage to change it?

Comment: If you are using the Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target dialog in order to use a remote server address, download the latest iFix which fixes this. If you are not using this (it is not required for local development testing), then you can simply edit the wlclient.properties file and enter the correct IP address of your host machine.

Comment: I tried with creating a new hybrid app from fresh (no any application code), still getting the same alert dialog in Android Simulator when preview. Do you see this alert dialog when you do preview with Android simulator?

Comment: I upgraded to 7.1.0.00-20150929-154, recreated the a Hello project/app,  and I see the same alert dialog. I am wondering if it has anything to do with upgrade?

Comment: Provide your MobileFirst project. Upload to Dropbox.